# How to get the first entity from linked entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the

```
Class User  {

@OneToMany
    private $profiles
}
```

Now I have the $user entity in my controller but I also want the first or last profile based on date. How can I achieve this?

I have the method `getProfiles()` but I think that will return the array collection.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$user->getProfiles()->first()
```

will do it, as long as you are declaring the `$profiles` property as a

```
\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
```

in the constructor of your class.

Comment: thanks buddy that worked  where can i find this in doctrine documentaion

Comment: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: I am doing the same but I am getting full object instead of array. Can you check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488328/doctine-and-zf2

Comment: i have return this in __construct()         $this->code = new ArrayCollection();
         $this->code2 = $this->code->first();

Comment: i have return this in __construct() 
 

     $this->languageObj = new ArrayCollection();

when we print it is gives this

       

     [languageObj:User:private] => Common\User\Entity\Language Object
                (
                    [languageId:Language:private] => 1
                    [languageCode:Language:private] => en
                    [languageName:Language:private] => English
                    [languageCode2:Language:private] => User Object
 *RECURSION*
                )

I am not able to fetch languageCode from the object

Answer (score 17):

You can easily get the first one like that :

```
$first = $this->get('doctrine.manager')->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->findOneBy([]);
```

Comment: It's not "the first one", just "one", it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But it does. Both the answers have no sorting, so will take it as the DB provided it, and both return only the first. The difference being that this answer only retrieves the first